# Tcl procedure return vs. set as return operator

Tags: function, tcl, return-value

Let us say that I have a procedure, and I wish to return a value of a variable local to the procedure.
There are many ways to do that, but 2 very simple ones, are, at the very last line of the procedure puts either of these command (assume that ret stores the returned value)

```
set ret ; #first option
return $ret ; #second option
```

What is the difference (if any) under the hood, between the 2 in Tcl, that should prompt me to choose 1 or the other?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytecode sequence is effectively the same; both push the value onto the operand stack and call the `done` operation which terminates the procedure successfully. I usually prefer to use `return` as that's clearer as to what I mean.

Comment: One generates one extra unreachable bytecode. Like you need to care about that.

Comment: So, it is a little slower (the set)?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more idiomatic in Tcl to use `return`. Unlike, for example, Ruby where it is idiomatic to *avoid* using return.

Also, if you're returning a non-ok status, you really have to use return, so you might as well use it for ok statuses too.